Cannot ssh into host or access any hosted service, but WireGuard works
I'm having an extremely strange issue.
I have an Ubuntu server running a few docker containers (including a WireGuard server) on my home network. It has the IP 192.168.1.208. The WireGuard port 51820 has been forwarded using upnp-service, also hosted on docker.
I'm currently away from home and have been able to connect to my server using the WireGuard tunnel. A couple hours ago, randomly, I stopped being able to ssh into my 192.168.1.208 server while connected to the WireGuard server. I can access all other computers on the network and my home router page at 192.168.1.1, but strangely, none of my other docker containers hosted on 192.168.1 208.
I've tried sshing into another PC while connected to WireGuard (this works), and then sshing into my server from that PC, but that doesn't work either. I can, however, ping 192.168.1.208 from the second PC.
I don't assume the server has shit the bed because clearly, docker is still running on it with WireGuard and upnp-service at the very least still working. Why can I not access any other container or ssh into it then?
